# Tener dos ramas paralelas en github

Tags: github, ramas-git

estoy desarrollando un proyecto que tengo en un repositorio de github. En éste tengo dos ramas, una de "dev" donde realizo las modificaciones, y otra "v1" que es la que utilizo para probar esos cambios desplegándolo con un Jenkins.

El problema es que la rama "dev" tiene archivos de configuración que no quiero que tenga la rama "v1" y viceversa.

¿Cual es la forma correcta de pushear y actualizar las dos ramas con los cambios que hago en "dev" pero sin que me modifique los archivos de resources y de confing de cada una de las ramas?

Gracias.

Comment: Evita preguntar por _la mejor manera_ ya que así haces que tu pregunta sea basada en opiniones, por lo cual terminaría [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Yo creo que si estas necesitando tener ramas divergentes es mas bien un anti-patron que podría indicar mejor separar en dos proyectos distintos. Otra opción es manejarlo a travez de configuraciones o variables de ambiente.